is there a way through mel/python to activate specific fields in the chanell editor editor?
By active I mean highlight the attributes field blue, so that a middle mouse button drag will change that attributes value.
The reason why I am asking this is that 70% of the time when I apply a command I just need to change one attribute. For example, when I apply a bevel, I only need to increment the fraction attribute.
For example, I am thinking of creating a hotkey/shelf item that will

Apply the bevel command to a selection
Then make the "Fraction" field the active field in the Chanell editor

Then I just need hold down middle mouse button to increment its value.
I want general shelf items/ custom command hotkeys along with line.
In order to do this I need a way to do the following:

Activate a specific attribute in the Chanell editor
Activate the next attribute (the one below current attribute)
Activate the previous attribute (the one above current attribute)

So I guess, I am asking are there specific Mel/python commands for working with the attribute editor?
I have search the hotkey window for any such commands that relate to the Chanell editor and surprisingly there is only one item, toggle the Chanell editor window. I also searched the Mel 2025 reference and did not find anything promising.
Thank you for any help or input
